# How can I create an IPsec tunnel between a FritzBox and a pfsense, without using Aggressive Mode?

Tags: security, tunnel, pfsense, ipsec, fritzbox

I've successfully created an IPSEC Tunnel between my local FritzBox 7590 and my office, which is running a pfsense hardware firewall (APU2) with pfsense 2.4.5-RELEASE-p1 and coreboot firmware v4.11.0.6.

However, the tunnel only works with Aggressive Mode enabled, which produces the following pfsense log entries:

> /rc.newipsecdns: WARNING: Setting i_dont_care_about_security_and_use_aggressive_mode_psk option because a phase 1 is configured using aggressive mode with pre-shared keys. This is not a secure configuration.

How can I create a secure tunnel between these locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has bugged me since 2 years and I only found out recently how to connect without Aggressive Mode. I am posting my answer here, in case someone else has the same question. Almost any guide I found uses Aggressive Mode, which is not necessary if correctly configured.

The following parameters apply:

- FritzBox has a dynamic ip address and is registered to myFritz.net. You'll get a DynDNS-Name that is updated with the most recent IP address.
- pfsense has a static, public IP address. If this is not the case, you'll need to use another DynDNS Service to broadcast pfsense IP
- I suggest to update pfsense and FritzBox to the most recent firmware, as a means to support modern crytographic hashing
- To ease testing the IPSEC tunnel with two remote locations, first configure your pfsense with OpenVPN so you'll be able to configure pfsense from your other location
- FritzBox LAN is configured with `192.168.178.0` and pfsense LAN is configured with `192.168.10.0`. This can be changed, but both LANs cannot be the same.

The key to disabling Aggressive Mode is to load the VPN configuration via import. The FritzBox interface  hides most of the important stuff, which is why Aggressive Mode can only be disabled when using the import function.

## FritzBox configuration

This is my `ipsec-fritzbox.cfg`, I'll explain parameters and pfsense configuration below:

```json
vpncfg {
connections {
  enabled = yes;
  conn_type = conntype_lan;
  name = "FritzBox-pfsense IPSEC"; // Name of Connection
  always_renew = yes; // Always connect
  reject_not_encrypted = no;
  dont_filter_netbios = yes;
  localip = 0.0.0.0;
  local_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
  remoteip = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; // Static IP of pfsense
  remote_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
  localid {
    fqdn = "xxx.myfritz.net"; // dyndns name of FritzBox
    }
  remoteid {
    ipaddr = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; // Static IP of pfsense
    }
  mode = phase1_mode_idp;
  phase1ss = "dh14/aes/sha"; //phase one hashing algorithms to use
  keytype = connkeytype_pre_shared;
  key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //strong pre-shared key
  cert_do_server_auth = no;
  use_nat_t = no;
  use_xauth = no;
  use_cfgmode = no;
  phase2localid {
    ipnet {
      ipaddr = 192.168.178.0; //Local network of FritzBox
      mask = 255.255.255.0; //Local subnet FritzBox
      }
    }
  phase2remoteid {
    ipnet {
      ipaddr = 192.168.10.0; //Remote network of Pfsense
      mask = 255.255.255.0; //Remote subnet Pfsense
      }
    }
  phase2ss = "esp-aes256-3des-sha/ah-no/comp-lzs-no/pfs"; //phase two hashing algorithms to use
  accesslist = "permit ip any 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"; //firewall settings for pfsense lan
  }
  ike_forward_rules = "udp 0.0.0.0:500 0.0.0.0:500",
                      "udp 0.0.0.0:4500 0.0.0.0:4500";
}
```

## pfsense configuration

In the pfsense web interface, go to VPN > IPsec and click Add

### Phase 1

#### General Information

Remote Gateway: Enter the DynDNS name of the FritzBox

[image]

#### Phase 1 Proposal (Authentication)

Peer identifier: Enter the DynDNS name of the FritzBox
Pre-Shared Key: Enter a strong static key.
Negotiation Mode: Main (not aggressive)
My identifier: in case of DynDNS, use Distinguished Name; otherwise the static public IP of the pfsense

[image]

#### Phase 1 Proposal (Encryption Algorithm)

You'll want to use modern encryption algorithms. Below I used AES with 256 bits and SHA1 (Hash) and DH Group 14 (2048 bit). DH14 only worked for me with a Lifetime of 3600 (not 28800).

This results in the following phase2ss entry of the `ipsec-fritzbox.cfg`:

```
mode = phase1_mode_idp;
phase1ss = "dh14/aes/sha";
```

[image]

#### Advanced Options

I haven't changed anything here.

[image]

### Phase 2

Save settings and add a phase 2 entry with the following configuration.

#### General Information

[image]

#### Phase 2 Proposal (SA/Key Exchange)

I've used ESP with AES (256 bits) and 3DES (Encryption) and SHA1 (Hash) with a Lifetime of 3600 seconds. This results in the following phase2ss entry of the `ipsec-fritzbox.cfg`:

```
phase2ss = "esp-aes256-3des-sha/ah-no/comp-lzs-no/pfs";
```

[image]

#### Advanced Configuration

Add the local IP of the FritzBox here.

[image]

## Check connection

Once this is configured, you'll see the status under Status > IPsec in the pfsense:

[image]

In the FritzBox, have a look at Log Enties under System. Initial connections might fail due to the FritzBox reconnecting to a new IP, which needs to be broadcast to the DynDNS service. After a few minutes, the Connection Status in the Main Dashboard should turn green.

This worked for me for a while now. Any comments or improvements appreciated!

**Problems:**

For any problems, check **Status > System Logs > IPsec**, which gives you the live logging from pfsense ipsec.

For example, I had problems with getting dh14 to work (instead of dh1 or dh2). I could solve this by using Sha1 as hashing (instead of sha512), checking 3des (in addition to aes) and reducing the lifetime to 3600 (instead of 28800).

Also note that this setup gets increasingly complicated if both sites work on DynDNS. In fact, `mode = phase1_mode_idp;` entry is only possible with a static remote site.

**Caveats**:

If anyone gets dh14 to work with Sha512 hashing (instead of sha1), and without 3des, please add a comment. According to the FritzBox docs, Sha512 or Sha256 should be possible, but no combination for using a sha other than sha1 in phase 1 or 2 worked for me. Also, I had to leave 3des for encryption enabled (proposal 2), otherwise I would not be able to use dh14 (without 3des worked only when using dh1 or dh2).

As far as I know, the FritzBox still only supports IKEv1.

**Readthedocs**:

The following two doc entries should provide some additional knwowledge:

- [FritzBox IPsec](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7590/knowledge-base/publication/show/3331_Connecting-the-FRITZ-Box-with-a-company-s-VPN/)
- [Pfsense IPsec Troubleshooting](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/troubleshooting/ipsec.html)